# Adding a margin between two bootstrap columns makes them stack on top of each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap columns, [side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5pjN.png), but when I add a margin to separate them then the columns [stack on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3sCE.png) of each other. I am using the Mixed: mobile, tablet, and desktop grid template for my two columns, and I'm not sure whether this is the cause.

```css
#antGame { // container
    height: 60%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

#stimuliContainer {
    height: 40%;
}

#stimuli {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#errorMsg {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}

#antInstruct {
    height: 60%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8" id="antGame">
            <div id="stimuliContainer">
                <img id="stimuli" src="images/ant/cues/blank.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8" id="errorMsg">
                <span>Error Message</span>
            </div>
        </div>
     
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4" id="antInstruct">
            <h4>Instructions</h4>
            <span>Hi</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the `CSS` rule, which actually adds this `margin`?

Comment: have you tried col-md-offset-1 in div ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend to override the padding of the Bootstrap columns, because it can break the responsive, but you know, *sometimes* you are forced to do it.

In that case the most clean way you can do, is add a custom class *.padding-2*, that overrides the Boostrap padding but don't destroy the responsive.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 padding-2 ">
        <div style="border: 1px black solid; background-color: red;">
          1 col
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 padding-2 ">
        <div style="border: 1px black solid;  background-color: blue;">
          2 col
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.padding-2 {
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/eO033QYCn3

Comment: I want the two columns to be separated by around 2px. I have managed to do this by changing the width using the ID selectors #antGame and #antInstruct, but this breaks the responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use padding instead of margin, and then, if you want to have for example border, you can add another element inside this one with padding.

Here's an example:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding: 5px">
        <div style="border: 1px black solid;">
          1 col
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding: 5px">
        <div style="border: 1px black solid;">
          2 col
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And demo:

https://plnkr.co/edit/5fCMTJMJWPALk3W45t1i?p=preview